# How to change icon submenu

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Hello can anybody tell me how to change that + icon to an arrow can somebody help me

here is my code

```
.special-header-menu .sub-menu-controller {
url ('#');
}
```

But still cannot change it

[IMG OF IT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSC3g.png)   `[MYWEBLINK][2]`

Comment: You should probably share how the plus is assigned, the screenshot does not help at all. You already have a typo in your code, as there is a whitespace between url and your brackets. A simple "#" is not a valid url() value see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please, try to elaborate the issue more and provide some code. According to my understanding of your problem, I think you can use a conditionally updating css `class` for toggling down the `display` property and setting it to `display : none` when you have clicked the `+` button by listening to an `onClick` event or checking if there are child `div` inside that particular parent `div` of the button

Comment: Yes thank you when i add display:none; to there is not no dropdown option so i need a css code i think that i can hide that or replace it with another one

Comment: Or without css you can have a variable to check whether the div is open or not and conditionally render the icon of + or arrow in the UI.